# Problems with Series and Map

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

Consider the two following ways to write down the same expression

```
ff1 = {(a - b)*Log[2 - z]*Log[z]*PolyLog[2, z/2] - 
    2*(a - b)*Log[z]*PolyLog[3, (2 - z)/2] + (7*(a - b)*Log[z]*Zeta[3])/4};

ff2 = {(a - b)*Log[z]*(Log[2 - z]*PolyLog[2, z/2] - 
      2*PolyLog[3, (2 - z)/2] + (7*Zeta[3])/4)};
```

Using `Simplify[ff1 - ff2]` we can easily check that the two expressions are identical. Now let us expand both expressions around `z=0` using `Series` and `Map`

```
seriesFu[ex_] := 
 Normal[Series[#, {z, 0, 0}, Assumptions -> {z > 0}]] & /@ ex
r1 = seriesFu /@ ff1
r2 = seriesFu /@ ff2
```

This yields

```
{-2 \[Zeta](3) (a-b) log(z)+7/4 (a \[Zeta](3) log(z)-b \[Zeta](3) log(z))+1/2 z (a log(2) log(z)-b log(2) log(z))}
{-(1/4) \[Zeta](3) (a-b) log(z)}
```

Surprisingly, in Mathematica 11.2 `r1` and `r2` are not the same, since

```
Simplify[r1 - r2]
```

returns

```
{1/2 z log(2) (a-b) log(z)}
```

Notice that if we apply `Series` directly, the difference vanishes, as it should.

```
s1 = Normal[Series[ff1, {z, 0, 0}, Assumptions -> {z > 0}]]
s2 = Normal[Series[ff2, {z, 0, 0}, Assumptions -> {z > 0}]]
Simplify[s1 - s2]
```

gives

```
{1/4 (b \[Zeta](3) log(z)-a \[Zeta](3) log(z))}

{-(1/4) \[Zeta](3) (a-b) log(z)}

{0}
```

Mathematica 11.1 is also affected, while Mathematica 11.0 and Mathematica 10.3 do not have this problem.

I noticed this behavior, because a calculation I did with Mathematica 11.0 gave me completely wrong results once I evaluated the same notebook with the version 11.2.

Can someone reproduce this issue? Is it a bug, or have there been some fundamental changes in the way `Series` works? Are there workarounds?

Edit: I'm afraid that my question was misunderstood. I'm well aware of the intricacies related to the expansion of functions around their singularities. But this is not what I'm asking. My point is that Mathematica versions before and after 11.1 give completely different result for the same piece of code and I want to understand why.

I made few more tests and it seems that the issue is related to `Normal` not `Map`. Consider the following

```
ff1 = (a - b)*Log[2 - z]*Log[z]*PolyLog[2, z/2] - 
   2*(a - b)*Log[z]*
    PolyLog[3, (2 - z)/2] + (7*(a - b)*Log[z]*Zeta[3])/4;
ff2 = (a - b)*
   Log[z]*(Log[2 - z]*PolyLog[2, z/2] - 
     2*PolyLog[3, (2 - z)/2] + (7*Zeta[3])/4);
```

and

```
(Series[#, {z, 0, 0}, Assumptions -> {z > 0}] & /@ (ff1)) // Simplify
(Series[#, {z, 0, 0}, Assumptions -> {z > 0}] & /@ (ff2)) // Simplify
Simplify[% - %%]
```

Even though here `Series` is applied to each term separately, it still produces  identical results.

```
1/4 \[Zeta](3) (b-a) log(z)+O(z^1)

-(1/4) \[Zeta](3) (a-b) log(z)+O(z^1)

O(z^1)
```

However, with `Normal` we observe the behavior that I described earlier

```
(Normal[Series[#, {z, 0, 0}, 
      Assumptions -> {z > 0}]] & /@ (ff1)) // Simplify
(Normal[Series[#, {z, 0, 0}, 
      Assumptions -> {z > 0}]] & /@ (ff2)) // Simplify
Simplify[% - %%]
```

gives

```
1/4 (a-b) log(z) (z log(4)-\[Zeta](3))

-(1/4) \[Zeta](3) (a-b) log(z)

1/4 z log(4) (b-a) log(z)
```

Notice that with versions 11.0, 10.3 and 9.0 both codes give the same results.
This example might be somewhat artificial, but I think that it clearly shows
that something fundamental in `Series`/`Normal` was changed in version 11.1.
This is what I hope to understand, to avoid such pitfalls when running same
codes on different Mathematica versions.

I guess WRI would say that applying `Series` to each term separately is undefined behavior so that one cannot expect any consistency across different versions.

Comment: For comparison purposes, can you investigate what happens if you use `Limit[]` with `Direction -> -1`?

Comment: You should isolate an example that gets rid of all the junk. There are unneeded lists and `Map` that only serve to confuse things. The answer by @BobHanlon appears to show the results are essentially equivalent once the confusing clutter is removed. If you want to claim otherwise then a minimal example that shows the actual discrepancy is needed.

Comment: Please evaluate the five last code blocks (after Edit:...) in my question on a Mathematica version 11.2 and a version earlier than 11.1 (e.g. 11.0 or 10.3). There are no lists there and you will see that the results do not agree. As I already wrote, for MMA 11.1 and 11.2 this depends on whether one uses  `Normal` or not. Earlier versions give the same output regardless of `Normal`.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a bug, but normal behavior of Series.

The first term of Series for a function f at z=0 is f[0].

```
Series[f[x], {x, 0, 0}] // Normal
```

All functions, that are not defined at 0, are given back unevaluated by Series, because it makes no sense to give back -Infinity.

```
ser0 = Series[Log[z] Cos[z - w], {z, 0, 0}, Assumptions -> z > 0] // 
        Normal

(*    Cos[w] Log[z]     *)
```

The ff1 and ff2 can both be splitted in 3 terms, but with different limit at z=0.

```
Plot[Evaluate[(List @@ ff1) /. {a -> 1, b -> 2.5}], {z, -2, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> 8]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[(List @@ ff2) /. {a -> 1, b -> 2.5}], {z, -2, 2}, 
   PlotRange -> 8]
```

[image]

With ff1 there are two terms with Infinity-Limit at z=0 and therfore two terms are given back partly unevaluated by Series.

With ff2 there is only one term given back unevaluated and therefore you get  different Series of the two functions.

```
ns1 = Normal[
Series[#, {z, 0, 0}, Assumptions -> {z > 0}]] & /@ (List @@ ff1)

(*     {0, -2 (a - b) Log[z] Zeta[3], 
           7/4 (a Log[z] Zeta[3] - b Log[z] Zeta[3])}     *)

ns2 = Normal[
        Series[#, {z, 0, 0}, Assumptions -> {z > 0}]] & /@ (List @@ ff2)

(*     {a - b, Log[z], -(Zeta[3]/4)}     *)
```

Comment: Good analysis, but what I wanted to point out is the difference between the results from  version 11.1 and above and previous versions. When you apply `List` to `ff1` and `ff2`, you are really forcing `Series` to look at each term separately. However, I believe that this is not how it behaves (or used to behave) in my examples. It seems to be something related to `Normal` not `Map` as I originally assumed. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: By applying Map to ff1, ff2 you too force Series to look at each term separately.

Comment: First: By applying Map to ff1, ff2 you too force Series to look at each term separately.  `ff1//Length`shows ff1 to be composed of three parts. With `Map`they are treated separately and added according to their sign at the end. Second: With Version 8.0 I also get the same results for `(Normal[Series[#, {z, 0, 0}, 
      Assumptions -> {z > 0}]] & /@ (ff1)) // Simplify
(Normal[Series[#, {z, 0, 0}, 
      Assumptions -> {z > 0}]] & /@ (ff2)) // Simplify
Simplify[% - %%]`. Your result with Vers. 11.2 seems to have sign-errors. Give the first and last line a (-) to get 0.

Comment: You don't have version 11.1 or 11.2  to test yourself?

Comment: Your answer actually shows that when `Series` is looking separately at each term of `ff1` and `ff2`, the final results should differ. However, on older Mathematica versions this is not the case, which is why I suspect that despite `Map` there `Series` still somehow looks at the full expression. It is also not so clear to me why having or not having `Normal` should change the two results on 11.1 and 11.2. This is why I would not call this behavior of `Series` normal. At least I do not understand it.

Comment: BTW, on Mathematica 8 my original code with `r1 = seriesFu /@ ff1` and `r2 = seriesFu /@ ff2` produces the same results.

Comment: Ok, as you describe, it seems realy to be a problem of Versions 11.1 and 11.2. I don't have that versions. As I mentioned before, change one or two signs of the three summands of your Version 11.2 solution and you get the desired equality. A sign error of V. 11.2 and 11.1.  ?!

Answer (score 2):

```
ff1 = {(a - b)*Log[2 - z]*Log[z]*PolyLog[2, z/2] - 
    2*(a - b)*Log[z]*PolyLog[3, (2 - z)/2] + (7*(a - b)*Log[z]*Zeta[3])/4};

ff2 = {(a - b)*
    Log[z]*(Log[2 - z]*PolyLog[2, z/2] - 
      2*PolyLog[3, (2 - z)/2] + (7*Zeta[3])/4)};

Simplify[ff1 - ff2]

(* {0} *)
```

`Map` is included in your definition of `seriesFu` so you do not want to `Map` `seriesFu` onto the components of `ff1` and `ff2`, i.e., just use `@`

```
seriesFu[ex_] := Normal[Series[#, {z, 0, 0}]] & /@ ex
r1 = seriesFu@ff1 // Simplify
r2 = seriesFu@ff2

(* {1/4 (-a + b) Log[z] Zeta[3]}

{-(1/4) (a - b) Log[z] Zeta[3]} *)

Simplify[r1 - r2]

(* {0} *)
```

It is not clear why you are using extraneous `List` brackets.

Comment: The example is admittedly somewhat artificial and possibly not well defined. First I though that it was something related to `Map` but it looks like the real reason is `Normal`. I edited my question accordingly. Actually I'm just trying to understand why different Mathematica versions give me different results. Obviously, one would normally not map a `Plus` to `Series`, but I'm curious to know what was changed under the hood of version 11.1 to produce this discrepancy.